# Installed headers don't exist according to GCC

Tags: gtk, gcc

I want to compile [Pike](http://pike.ida.liu.se) with the GTK library. To do this, I need the `gtk` headers installed.

```
$ tee test.cpp test.c
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
$ g++ test.cpp; gcc test.c                                                                                                                                   
test.cpp:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
test.c:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I looked around a bit and found the packages to install.

```
$ apt install libgtk-3-dev libgtk2.0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgtk2.0-dev is already the newest version.
libgtk-3-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Okay...

```
$ sudo ls -Ral /usr/include/ | grep gtk
<617 lines of proof snipped...>
$ !! | wc -l
617
```

???

```
$ sudo find /usr/include -name "*gtk*" | wc -l
567
```

The headers are there; I know they are. Why can't `gcc` find them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't told g++ *where* to find them: by default, it only looks in the top-level `/usr/include` directory, whereas the headers you are trying to include are in a `gtk-2.0` subdirectory.

You can either add the include path manually e.g.

```
gcc -I /usr/include/gtk-2.0 test.c
```

or (the recommended way) use `pkg-config` to pull the required paths and flags directly from the package's supplied `.pc` file

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` test.c
```

If you actually use any symbols from the included library, you will likely need to do the same for the linker path e.g.

```
gcc test.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

See for example [Compiling GTK+ Applications on UNIX](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk-compiling.html) from the [GNOME Developer Center](https://developer.gnome.org/)

Comment: I just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24956495/4532996) which gives the exact answer I was looking for, and I was writing a self-answer when you posted this. Thanks! :)